# How to edit Team Members from Drupal site

Tags: views, nodes, blocks

I have been tasked with updating my companies website done in Drupal and I can find dozens of ways and places to configure a block, I just cannot find where I can make a simple, basic edit to the content and remove a Team Member.

When I use the search toolbar in Drupal it directs me only to the instances/ mentions of the Team Member block and NOT the actual list of Team Members. I've found the Tiers that are used to place them in the block, but still no actual list of said Team Members.

I don't know if my attached screenshot is at all helpful, but any suggestions on where to find these Team Members would be appreciated. BTW, they are not a part of the 'People' admins of the site.

[image: Configure Team Block/ Role Field]

Comment: you want to remove the Team Member from the Filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attached screenshot in your question is a bit tough to digest, but it shows just enough details to suggest an alternative approach/solution to what you're trying to do ... and which should also work for any user who does not have authority to use any path starting with `/admin`.

#### 1. Browse your views page results

After you closed the popup window, use the <kbd>View page</kbd> button included in (the right of) your screenshot, to show the actual "list" of all *Team members* in a page with title "*Team grid*".

From the "*Filter criteria*"-section included in (the left of) your screenshot, it seems that your list (or "grid") includes 1 entry (= a row included in the query results of your View) for each (published) "*node*" of content type `Blog Author` or `Team member`.

From the "*Fields*"-section included in (the left of) your screenshot, it seems that this list (or "grid") should at least show you these data about each of the included Team member:

- Title
- Job Title
- Picture

Use these data to decide which Team member you need to process (as detailed in step 2 below).

#### 2. Select the Team member to be removed

It's impossible to tell from your screenshot, but pretty sure that for each Team member shown in your list (grid), you'll be able to click on it, to "*view*" more details about the Team member you selected. After you do so, you'll (probably) be viewing the actual *node* of the Team member you selected.

#### 3. Edit/delete the Team member

Assuming *you* have permission to edit nodes of content type Team member, you'll have an <kbd>Edit</kbd> tab and a <kbd>View</kbd> (maybe even other tabs).

Use (click) <kbd>Edit</kbd> and scroll down to the bottom, to locate the buttons <kbd>Save</kbd>, <kbd>Preview</kbd> and <kbd>***Delete***</kbd>.

To finish, just hit the <kbd>***Delete***</kbd> button, confirm you want to do so ... voilà, gone is the Team member.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably find what you need at /admin/content. What you are looking at is the views interface to build a list - the list doesn't exist anywhere but in your database, and it won't exist in the database as a list, it will just be separate rows in the database table, so don't bother looking there. The list is build from the database, using the interface that you have shown a screenshot of.

You should be able to find the various items you want at /admin/content. You may have to filter by a content type, depending on how much content is on your site.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I had to enter the Team Members name in Title, Type and THEN I was able to find them.